# Add and Multiply Functions in Java return wrong result

Tags: java, tostring, complex-numbers

I am doing a very basic **Complex Numbers class in Java** but when I test my add and multiply functions I don't get the results I expect. I don't understand what is wrong or how to fix it.

When I run the program I get the following output:

**a+b: ComplexNumber@1540e19d**

**a*b: ComplexNumber@677327b6**

I should get the proper addition and multiplication of two complex numbers (following the rules of complex numbers of course)

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
public class ComplexNumber {

private double real;
private double imaginary;

public ComplexNumber(double r, double i) {
    real = r;
    imaginary = i;
}

public double real() {
    return real;
}

public double imaginary() {
    return imaginary;
}

public ComplexNumber add(ComplexNumber c) {
    double newr = real + c.real();
    double newi = imaginary + c.imaginary();
    return new ComplexNumber(newr, newi);
}
public ComplexNumber multiply(ComplexNumber c) {
    double newr = real*c.real() - imaginary*c.imaginary();
    double newi = real*c.imaginary() + imaginary*c.real();
    return new ComplexNumber(newr, newi);
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    ComplexNumber c1 = new ComplexNumber(1.0, 2.0);
    ComplexNumber c2 = new ComplexNumber(-1.0, 0.5);
    String c1plusc2 = c1.add(c2).toString();
    String c1timesc2 = c1.multiply(c2).toString();

    System.out.println("a+b :" + c1plusc2);
    System.out.println("a*b :" + c1timesc2);

    }
    }
```

Comment: You should really get into the habit of formatting your code properly. Especially since there are nowadays a lot of editors / IDEs that do it automatically. Otherwise you're showing disrespect to the people who read it.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov I actually wanted to do it but stackoverflow required 4 indentations in order to submit my code for each line and it took me forever. Any trick on how to move my code all 4 indents to the right at once? It is a hassle to do one line at a time!

Comment: I usually just select it in my IDE (NetBeans, but many other will work), press Tab to shift it right, then press Ctrl-C and Ctrl-Z (to undo the shift). But really, even without that (suppose you don't have an IDE at hand), if it's properly formatted, then only the first and the last lines (`class` and `}`) will be screwed up. Then just add 4 spaces to these lines and leave the rest untouched, and you end up with almost properly formatted code (and nobody will really mind those two lines if it's just one class anyway).

Comment: Now you call `toString()` and then assign the result to `ComplexNumber`. It won't even compile because the types aren't compatible. You should call `toString()` only when printing the result and moreover, it is done implicitly, so simple `"a+b :" + c1plusc2` will work just as fine as `"a+b :" + c1plusc2.toString()`.

Comment: @ChantalMarin In questions and answers in StackOverflow, maybe not so much comments, you can highlight the code and press Ctrl+K

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to override the `toString` method in the `ComplexNumber` class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return real + " + i*" + imaginary;
}
```

Your `.add()` & `.multiply()` methods return a `ComplexNumber` object. By default,

```
System.out.println("a*b :" + c1.multiply(c2));
```

evaluates to

```
System.out.println("a*b :" + c1.multiply(c2).toString());
```

The `toString()` method is inherited from the `Object` class (since all classes inherit from `Object`). And since you're not **overriding** it in the `ComplexNumber` class, you get the default return value from `Object`'s `toString()` method:

```
ClassName@hashCodeOfTheObject
```

**EDIT:**

`toString()` returns a `String`. Change

```
ComplexNumber c1plusc2 = c1.add(c2).toString();
ComplexNumber c1timesc2 = c1.multiply(c2).toString();
```

to

```
String c1plusc2 = c1.add(c2).toString();
String c1timesc2 = c1.multiply(c2).toString();
```

Output:

```
a+b :0.0 + i*2.5
a*b :-2.0 + i*-1.5
```

Comment: I tend to agree, but this also means that you are not printing a value, you are just printing the String version of Type@memoryAddress

Comment: String version of what ?

Comment: objects in Java are seen as a Type (what class it is an instance of) at some memory address.  So, in your case it is saying the method returned an object of type ComplexNumber that lives at memory address 1540e19d, so it prints out the String  
"ComplexNumer@1540e19d"

Comment: That's not a memory address actually, it's the **hashcode** of that particular `ComplexNumber` instance.

Comment: How do you know that?  You have a reference/link/URL I can look at to verify that?  I'm not saying I don't believe you, but it comes as a surprise.

Comment: @MohammedAoufZOUAG it still doesn't work even though i added the toString Method and added the toString in my SystemOutPrintln. Any idea?                                       public static void main(String[] args) {
   
    ComplexNumber c1 = new ComplexNumber(1.0, 2.0);
    ComplexNumber c2 = new ComplexNumber(-1.0, 0.5);
    ComplexNumber c1plusc2 = c1.add(c2);
    ComplexNumber c1timesc2 = c1.multiply(c2);
    
    System.out.println("a+b :" + c1plusc2.toString());
    System.out.println("a*b :" + c1timesc2.toString());
    
    }

Comment: @Mohammed Cheers, I guess the hash of the object contains all information, including meta-information, so no two would likely be the same, but I never guessed that.  Thanks.

Comment: @CHANTALMARIN could you update the post with the full code ?

Comment: @plainOldNerd, since `hashCode` is native, I suppose it just boils down to the address or the hash code of the address on machines where address doesn't fit into 32 bits. Even the `hashCode` docs say: "This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer".

Comment: @MohammedAoufZOUAG Updated! Thanks for having a look :)

Comment: @MohammedAoufZOUAG That makes sense but it still doesn't work. Any other suggestion? Thanks! (I also edited the code with the last modifications you suggested!)

Comment: @CHANTALMARIN it's working fine for me, what seems to be the problem with the output ?

Comment: @MohammedAoufZOUAG I still get: a+b :ComplexNumber@1540e19d
a*b :ComplexNumber@677327b6

Comment: There is no way... Check if you're compiling & running an old version of the file.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov So effectively (not quite, but almost), it's Class @ memory address.  Anyway, thanks.  I'll checck out the hashCode docs sometime soon.